# How to get default kernel module name from *.ko files?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

Usually, the filename of a kernel module is the same as the module name. For example, after doing `insmod fuse.ko`, I can see `fuse` inserted in `/proc/modules`.

However, renaming the kernel module (`mv fuse.ko foo.ko`) doesn't affect the inserted module name. Doing `insmod foo.ko` still inserts `fuse` in `/proc/modules`.

Is there any system call or glibc function that can extract the module name from a kernel module file? In the previous example, I want to extract the name `fuse` from `foo.ko`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Name of the module is contained in *THIS_MODULE* module object (of type `struct module`). This object is stored in the kernel module file as a section `.gnu.linkonce.this_module`.

So, you may examine content of that section and find module's name there:

```
objdump -s -j .gnu.linkonce.this_module foo.ko
```

or

```
readelf -x .gnu.linkonce.this_module foo.ko
```

Module name is located at offset 12 (on 32-bit machine) or at offset 24 (on 64-bit machine).

---

`modinfo` doesn't print module's name. Probably, this is because offset of the name in the `struct module` structure is not standardized.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful to me :)

Comment: By the way, I wrote a little tool to print out the module name: https://github.com/johnlinp/kernel-module-name/

Comment: usefull stuff..

Answer (score 0):

you can use modinfo

```
# modinfo ./ec_sys.ko | grep "^name:"
name:           ec_sys
```

for a folder with *.ko files

```
# ls -l | grep -v '^d'  | awk '{print $9}'  | xargs -L1  -I% bash -c 'modinfo % | grep ^name'
```